# What is known about Ashaneloon?

Tags: elric-saga

What do we know about Ashaneloon, from Moorcock Canon?

In *The Vanishing Tower* we learn that it is a palace (with towers, so castle like?) on an island in the middle of the Boiling Sea. Not much. Is there something more we can find in the Saga of Elric?

Comment: I think all description of it is in *The Vanishing Tower*; I only found 1 other reference to it in "The Jade Man's Eyes" and it's just a mention of it without any additional details.

Comment: Not sure if this adds anything to what you already know: https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Ashaneloon  (There's more mention of it in the board games, although I couldn't find anything that really elaborated on it online)

Comment: Thanks @wcullen, yet unfortunately that summarized pretty much what is known from _The Vanishing Tower_. I should have a look at _The Jade Man's Eyes_ to see if there is something else to find out.

Comment: @Daemon Painter: ah, bummer :-)